# set_post_thumbnail_size not cropping featured images, but reducing proportionally

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

In my function file, I set the following:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 50, true );   
}
```

And in the loop:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail();  ?>
```

But the images are resized proportionally, using the smallest value. The crop is not working.

**UPDATE**

I change the function:

```
function resize_thumb () {
   add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
   set_post_thumbnail_size( 280, 80, true );
}

add_action ( 'after_setup_theme', 'resize_thumb' );
```

But the desire crop not happens.

**SOLVED**

In functions.php, I add just this line:

```
add_image_size( 'thumbnail-news', '190', '40', true );
```

And in the loop I add this line

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail-news' ); ?>
```

To resize old images, I use [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to Pieter, I'd say your if statement is correct (although, unnecessary). If it's a WordPress theme, then add_theme_support will likely exist!

Have you per chance added the images before setting the post thumbnail size? If so, you need to regenerate your images:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/